# Excel: Combine two arrays into one

Tags: arrays, excel, spreadsheet

I have two arrays, one contains text fields, the other dates:

**Array 1:**

```
Revenue
Gross Profit
Net Profit
```

**Array 2:**

```
2015
2014
2013
2012
2011
```

How can I create the following **output array** without using VBA?

```
Revenue 2015  
Revenue 2014  
Revenue 2013  
Revenue 2012  
Revenue 2011  
Gross Profit 2015  
Gross Profit 2014  
Gross Profit 2013  
Gross Profit 2012  
Gross Profit 2011 
. .
```

I have tried to use the array function `{=Array1&Array2}` but did not get the correct result.

Any ideas?

Comment: The array is one word per cell?

Comment: No, it can be a text string (multiple words) as well

Comment: i tried to add a screen shot from my excel, can you see it?

Comment: Do you want the output to be another array to be used in a formula (difficult) or a list which appears in the sheet (easier) ?

Answer (score 1):

I have some idea, I'm not sure if it will help. You can do it manually so it will be good only for a big arrays.
a1 = Revenue

a2 = Gross Profit

a3 = Net Profit

b1= 2015

b2= 2014

b3= 2013

b4=2012

[image: EXAMPLE]
**c2 -  =A1&B1**  - this is your calculate cell

**c3 -  =A1&B2**  - this is your calculate cell

And then mark the cells c2 and c3 and hold the Fill Handle and pull it down.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem and I stumbled upon this question while searching for a solution online. I didn't find anything that suits me, so I managed to solve it myself but it's not the most elegant solution.

You could use:

```
{=Array1&TRANSPOSE(Array2)}
```

which will create a matrix of a number of rows equal to your `array1` and a number of columns equal to your `array2`.

Of course, you must have first selected the area in your sheet where you want your matrix to be displayed, which must be of the appropriate `rowsxcolumns`.